# Want to select row equal to list in dataframe, 'Lengths must match to compare'

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, compare

Currently i have a dataframe looking like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col1 = [2, 3, 3, 2]
col2 = [[1,3,2], 4, 2, [1,2]]

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": col1, "B": col2})
   A   B
0  2   1,3,2
1  3   4
2  3   2
3  2   1,2
```

if i run `df.loc[df['B']== 4]` it runs fine. However if i try to run `df.loc[df['B']== [1,3,2]]` it gives me an error: 'Lengths must match to compare'. Is there a way i can compare a list within my pandas series? The desired outcome is ofcourse is the first row of index 0 as output.

Answer (score 2):

To compare with list you have to use `map`/`apply`:

```
df[df['B'].map(lambda x: x == [1, 3, 2])]
```

---

```
   A          B
0  2  [1, 3, 2]
```